# IBM node agent stops

Tags: websphere

i'm using IBM WAS 8.5 and IBM WCM 8
I developed a web app by using spring. So far so good... when I deploy it no problems
Now I needed to create a report and I used jasper report
My maven dependency tree is visible in the file "dep.log"
When I deploy the web app the nodeagent stops and I can't understand the reason
In the SystemOut.log I find:

```
[29/03/17 14.40.53:588 CEST] 0000003d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/PI/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/logs/ffdc/WebSphere_Portal_189b4c0d_17.03.29_14.40.53.5861801418936682921368.txt com.ibm.ws.dcs.vri.common.util.DCSDiagnosticModule.causeDump 100
```

[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5MNZMc-JYluS3ZyTnZxVzlVajg?usp=sharing) you can find the `WebSphere_Portal_189b4c0d_17.03.29_14.40.53.5861801418936682921368.txt` file and my `dependency tree` built by using maven

Any suggestion is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: The error message for the exception in the FFDC includes "Spazio heap Java" - I wonder if that's a sign that you've exhausted heap space, and the JVM is simply crashing.  It might be worth checking the native_stderr and native_stdout logs, as sometimes really low-level errors end up there.

Comment: @Jarid Yes I was thinking the same thing.... I talked with my System Administrator (it's a pre-production server) but till now we don't know how to solve it